# How to instantiate a <code></code> element in JavaScript (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

The [`HTMLPreElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLPreElement) type in JavaScript produces a DOM element corresponding to the `<pre>` tag. Where is the type corresponding to `<code>`? It seems there should be an `HTMLCodeElement` type, but there isn't. How do I go about instantiating this in NodeJS JavaScript?

Comment: "*How do I go about instantiating this in NodeJS JavaScript?*" - where are you getting a `HTMLPreElement` from in node.js? Given that there is no builtin DOM in node.js, you must be using a library. Which one?

Answer (score 0):

```
const c0d3 = document.createElement("code");
Object.getPrototypeOf(c0d3).constructor.toString();
//function(){return a.Reflect.construct(a.HTMLElement,[],this.constructor)}
```

At least on the browser side (Chrome, on node side you possibly have other workarounds to create mock DOM elements), it is not directly a distinct constructor, but rather a wrapper function that makes use of `HTMLElement` itself and another function `this.constructor` that is passed as an argument to [Reflect.construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct).

The old way of creating these native constructors are generally something like:

```js
//Instances inherit from parent proto
HTMLSomeChildElementFunc.prototype = Object.create(HTMLSomeParentElementFunc.prototype);

//Statics are inherited on the constructor
Object.setPrototypeOf(HTMLSomeCHildElement, HTMLSomeParentElement);
```

In this case it is a bit different, they went for some sort of monkey patch.

Comment: On what browser do you get `function(){return a.Reflect.construct(a.HTMLElement,[],this.constructor)}`? Any installed extensions? I do get `function HTMLElement() { [native code] }` as expected.

Comment: I get it on Chrome 97.0.4692.99

Comment: What you get is probably because they deleted the `toString` property on the constructor and it returns the nearest ancestor constructor's `toString`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99. Even if I try `Function.prototype.toString.call(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi Figured it out. It is on Stackoverflow's page.  :) So they went for the monkey patch :)